# Preserving List selection when you have selectable items that are contained within a VStack

Tags: macos, swiftui, swiftui-list

I want to have a List that gives the user the ability to select items (and therefore use up/down keyboard navigation on the Mac to navigate the list). Due to the complexity of views, I am using children elements within the List that contain selectable items. For simplification purposes, this is a minimum example of what I’m trying to do.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selectedItem: Obj?
    
    @State var demoData: [Obj] = [.init("Bardi"), .init("John")]
    
    var body: some View {
        List(selection: $selectedItem) {
            VStack {
                ForEach(demoData, id: \.self) { item in
                    Item(item: item)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct Obj: Hashable {
    var id: UUID = .init()
    var name: String = ""
    
    init(_ name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}

struct Item: View {
    var item: Obj
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(item.name)
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is the addition of the VStack breaks list selection. If I remove it, it works fine and as expected. I assume the VStack is preventing the List from properly detecting the individual items within the ForEach as selectable.

Is there any way to work around this? It seems a simple ask: I want a list with children subviews that categorise list items.

Comment: What is it you want to categorise, what is the purpose of the VStack?

Comment: I have different custom sections within each embedded VStack. For example, one contains a list of tasks for the day as well as a TextField to add another task. If the workaround involves _not_ depending on a List, then that is fine. But from my research, to facilitate keyboard selection between items in a regular ScrollView has its own sets of problems (for example navigating to items that are not within view, and making it scroll into view).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only list *rows* can be selected. By wrapping your items in a `VStack`, the entire `VStack` becomes a single list row. You can add a `tag` with an `Obj` value to it, to be able to select the whole `VStack`, but you cannot select the things inside the `VStack`.

> For example, one contains a list of tasks for the day as well as a TextField to add another task.

In that case you can make the `TextField` a separate list row on its own.

```
List(selection: $selectedItem) {
    ForEach(data, id: \.self) { item in
        Item(item: item)
    }
    TextField("New Item", text: $newItemName)
}
```

The list row with the `TextField` will not be selectable, because it has no `tag`. Note that the `ForEach` adds a `tag` to its views, with the value of that item's id.

You also said,

> I have different custom sections...

Great, then use `Section`s! You even mentioned it yourself.

Presumably your `VStack`s just contains the selectable items in the middle, then some unselectable views at the bottom (like the text field), and/or some unselectable views at the top. You can turn those unselectable views into the `Section`'s header and footer! Your `VStack`s are basically reinventing `Section`s.

Here is an example of a list with 2 sections:

```
List(selection: $selectedItem) {
    // in reality you'd use a ForEach to "loop through" the sections you have, of course
    Section {
        ForEach(group1Data, id: \.self) { item in
            Item(item: item)
        }
    } footer: {
        TextField("New Item", text: $newGroup1Item)
    }
    Section {
        ForEach(group2Data, id: \.self) { item in
            Item(item: item)
        }
    } footer: {
        TextField("New Item", text: $newGroup2Item)
    }
}
```

Comment: So simple and so obvious in hindsight. Thank you for the education!